# How to export an "IPython.lib.display.Audio" file as a mp3 or wav file?

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I have generated a music file for the first time. The music file type is "IPython.lib.display.Audio". I wanted to export it from colab to my local drive.I couldn't find any solution from google. Please help.

Comment: Did my answer solve our problem?

Answer (score 7):

The wave file content is stored in the `data` field, you may write the content to a file like this:

```
with open('/tmp/test.wav', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(audio.data)
```

Comment: But this saves to the remote server in which the python is running on. How to download using the browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the audio player and save the audio.
[image: Example]

Comment: in my case, this works with google colab, not jupyter notebook; but anyway, thanks; I ran code in jupyter notebook to display audio, then upload file to google colab for downloading

Answer (score 1):

```
soundfile.write(output_filename, audio_data, sample_rate)
```

output_filename: The output filename or a path to the output file
audio_data: The `<class 'IPython.lib.display.Audio'>` object
sample_rate: Based on your need.

https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#read-write-functions also gives a brief example. This should work whether you use colab/jupyter notebook or not.